# How to add data to shopware 6 storefront the right way?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

Hello i want to modify the price displayed on the storefront according to the customer on a b2b project but i am having a lot of trouble following the documentation so i need some help, thanks in advance. i tried to follow the documentation from this link https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-data-to-storefront-page, i am getting too many errors unfortunately.

First error was a typo:
[image]

the second error was about getdecorated() function not having the same data classes attached to them,

[image]

i modified the code  `public function getDecorated(): AbstractExampleRoute` of the documentation to  `public function getDecorated(): AbstractProductCountRoute`
i got a third error because the "use" lines were not the same,
[image]

i modified  `use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SalesChannel\ProductCountRoute;`
which does not exist and replaced the line with  `use Swag\BasicExample\Core\Content\Example\SalesChannel\ProductCountRoute;` then i got another error relating to the context [image]

i have tried to follow the documentation word by word but i am getting too many errors, what should i do? thank you for your answer.
here is my AddDataToPage.php

```php
    <?php declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Swag\BasicExample\Service;
    
    use Swag\BasicExample\Core\Content\Example\SalesChannel\ProductCountRoute;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Aggregation\Metric\CountAggregation;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\AggregationResult\Metric\CountResult;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Filter\EqualsFilter;
    use Shopware\Storefront\Pagelet\Footer\FooterPageletLoadedEvent;
    use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
    
    class AddDataToPage implements EventSubscriberInterface
    {
        private ProductCountRoute $productCountRoute;
    
        public function __construct(ProductCountRoute $productCountRoute)
        {
            $this->productCountRoute = $productCountRoute;
        }
    
        public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
        {
            return [
                FooterPageletLoadedEvent::class => 'addActiveProductCount'
            ];
        }
    
        public function addActiveProductCount(FooterPageletLoadedEvent $event): void
        {
            $productCountResponse = $this->productCountRoute->load(new Criteria(), $event->getContext());
    
            $event->getPagelet()->addExtension('product_count', $productCountResponse->getProductCount());
        }
    }
```

ProductCountRoute.php

```php
    <?php declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Swag\BasicExample\Core\Content\Example\SalesChannel;
    
    use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Exception\DecorationPatternException;
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\Entity;
    use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    
    /**
     * @Route(defaults={"_routeScope"={"store-api"}})
     */
    class ProductCountRoute extends AbstractProductCountRoute
    {
        protected EntityRepository $productRepository;
    
        public function __construct(EntityRepository $productRepository)
        {
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        }
    
        public function getDecorated(): AbstractProductCountRoute
        {
            throw new DecorationPatternException(self::class);
        }
    
        /**
         * @Entity("swag_get_active_product_count")
         * @OA\Post(
         *      path="/get-active-product-count",
         *      summary="This route can be used to get the count of all active products",
         *      operationId="readProductCount",
         *      tags={"Store API", "productCount"},
         *      @OA\Parameter(name="Api-Basic-Parameters"),
         *      @OA\Response(
         *          response="200",
         *          description="",
         *          @OA\JsonContent(type="object",
         *              @OA\Property(
         *                  property="productCount",
         *                  type="integer",
         *                  description="Total amount"
         *              )
         *          )
         *     )
         * )
         * @Route("/store-api/get-active-product-count", name="store-api.product-count.get", methods={"GET", "POST"})
         */
        public function load(Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $context): ProductCountRouteResponse
        {
            $criteria = new Criteria();
            $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('product.active', true));
            $criteria->addAggregation(new CountAggregation('productCount', 'product.id'));
    
            /** @var CountResult $productCountResult */
            $productCountResult = $this->productRepository
                ->aggregate($criteria, $event->getContext())
                ->get('productCount');
                
            return new ProductCountRouteResponse($productCountResult);
        }
    }
```

AbstractProductCountRoute.php

```php
    <?php declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Swag\BasicExample\Core\Content\Example\SalesChannel;
    
    use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
    use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
    
    abstract class AbstractProductCountRoute
    {
        abstract public function getDecorated(): AbstractProductCountRoute;
    
        abstract public function load(Criteria $criteria, SalesChannelContext $context): ProductCountRouteResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are all the previous errors you trial-and-error'd your way through relevant?

Aside from that, the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. You're passing the instance of the wrong class to the `load` method.

The `PageletLoadedEvent` abstract has getters for both `Context` and `SalesChannelContext`. You're calling `getContext` where you should be calling `getSalesChannelContext`.

```php
$productCountResponse = $this->productCountRoute->load(new Criteria(), $event->getSalesChannelContext());
```

Also in `ProductCountRoute::load` change `$event->getContext()` to `$context->getContext()`.